# Printing declared char value in C

Tags: c

I understand that character variable holds from (signed)-128 to 127 and (unsigned)0 to 255

```
char x;
x = 128;

printf("%d\n", x);
```

But how does it work? Why do I get `-128` for `x`?

Comment: google "two's complement"

Comment: And then google "sign extension" to understand why it stays negative when promoted to an int (%d) in the format string.

Comment: To understand why it stays negative, recall that C operates on values. A value of `-128` stays as `-128` when it is converted to another type for which `-128` is valid.  Regardless of representation (of which "sign extension" is an aspect)

Comment: @JohnH "sign extension" isn't relevant; if x is negative it stays negative when promoted to an int, regardless of how it is represented. Since the standard mandates that, sign extension is simply how a typical implementation would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` is a variadic function, only providing an exact type for the first argument.
That means the default promotions are applied to the following arguments, so all integers of rank less than `int` are promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`, and all floating values of rank smaller `double` are promoted to `double`.

If your implementation has `CHAR_BIT` of 8, and simple `char` is signed and you have an obliging 2s-complement implementation, you thus get

128 (literal) to -128 (`char`/`signed char`) to -128 (`int`) printed as `int` => -128

If all the listed condition but obliging 2s complement implementation are fulfilled, you get a signal or some implementation-defined value.

Otherwise you get output of 128, because 128 fits in `char` / `unsigned char`.

Standard quote for case 2 (Thanks to Matt for [unearthing the right reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691891/printing-declared-char-value-in-c/23691986#comment36404354_23692116)):

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>   2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
>   3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Answer (score 1):

This all has nothing to do with variadic functions, default argument promotions etc.

Assuming your system has signed chars, then `x = 128;` is performing an out-of-range assignment. The behaviour of this is *implementation-defined* ; meaning that the compiler may choose an action but it must document what it does (and therefore, do it reliably). This action is allowed to include raising a signal.

The usual behaviour that modern compilers do for out-of-range assignment is to truncate the representation of the value to fit in the destination type.

In binary representation, 128 is `000....00010000000`. 
Truncating this into a signed char gives the signed char of binary representation `10000000`. In [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which is used by all modern C systems for negative numbers, this is the representation of the value `-128`.   (For historical curiousity: in one's complement this is `-127`, and in sign-magnitude, this is `-0` which may be a trap representation and thus raise a signal).

Finally, `printf` accurately prints out this char's value of `-128`. The `%d` modifier works for `char` because of the default argument promotions and the facts that `INT_MIN <= CHAR_MIN` and `INT_MAX >= CHAR_MAX`.; this behaviour is guaranteed except on systems which have plain char as unsigned, and `sizeof(int)==1` (which do exist but you'd know about it if you were on one).

Comment: Out-of-range assignments are undefined behavior, not implementation-defined. From the standard, "If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @JimBalter, the text you quote is not describing out-of-range assignment. There is no exceptional condition during evaluation of an expression in `x = 128;`. The condition here is conversion from `int` to (signed) `char`, covered by C99 6.3.1.3

Comment: It certainly does describe that, as assignments are expressions. However, 6.3.1.3 does appear to apply here as it is specifically about assignment between integers of different types.

Comment: The `int` is converted to `char` before the assignment happens; assignment cannot proceed until the value on the right-hand-side has been converted to the type of the variable it's being assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the binary representation of `128` when stored into 8 bits:

> 1000 0000

And now let's look at the binary representation of `-128` when stored into 8 bits:

> 1000 0000

The standard for `char` with your current setup looks to be a `signed char` (note this isn't in the c standard, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default) if you don't believe me) and thus when you're assigning the value of `128` to `x` you're assigning it the value `1000 0000` and thus when you compile and print it out it's printing out the signed value of that binary representation (meaning `-128`).

It turns out my environment is the same in assuming `char` is actually `signed char`. As expected if I cast `x` to be an `unsigned char` then I get the expected output of `128`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char x;
  x = 128;
  printf("%d %d\n", x, (unsigned char)x);
  return 0;
}
```

gives me the output of `-128 128`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Minor nitpick: "assuming char is actually signed char" - `char` and `signed char` are distinct types, even though plain `char` is signed on your system.